# problem with <img image_path> vs <image_tag> with cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I wish to use the Image_tag in rails 5.2 like this:

```rb
<%= image_tag(@character.picture) %>
```

I get the following error:

```rb
"Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #<PictureUploader:0x00007f619c7fd000>"
```

I was successfully using

```rb
 <img src="<%= image_path(@character.picture) %>">
```

I am unsure why these two bits of code generate different results. Am I missing some quality with the image_tag? I can easily cut my losses and use the image_path option but aesthetically I would prefer to not have more html than needed in my code and wish to know why there is a difference in these two bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .......

```
<%= image_tag(@character.picture.url) %>
```

Hope this will help you.